# Можно ли сместить сразу несколько строк?

Tags: delphi, ide

Можно ли клавишей Tab сместить сразу несколько строк и как, если можно? У меня не получается. Может, это как-то можно сделать без клавиши Tab?

Comment: Мне тоже интересно. После навороченных IDEшек много чего не хватает.

Comment: На другом форуме подсказали - Ctrl+K+I и Ctrl+K+U.

Comment: @leklerk, это еще в турбопаскалях было да. там еще для выделения ctrl+k+b и ctrl+k+k...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Увеличить отступ Ctrl-Shift-I. Уменьшить Ctrl-Shift-U.

- D7: Tools - Editor preferences... Key mapping
- D2007: Tools-Options - Editor options - Editor speed setting

Там можно выбрать схему, может найдете привычную для себя...

Comment: Спасибо, есть такие настройки. Но Ctrl-Shift-I у меня не работает (у меня Turbo Delphi Professional (урезанная Delphi 2006)).

Comment: Еще есть вариант свои биндинги написать :)

    Start > Programs > Embarcadero RAD Studio > Samples and then navigate to Delphi\VCL\ToolsAPI\Editor KeyBinding

[см здесь](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeSamples/en/VCL.Editor_KeyBinding_Sample)

Comment: Спасибо. К сожалению, у меня не Embarcadero, а Borland :)

Comment: tools api появились чуть ли не со второй delphi, а может и с первой (не помню). название конторы роли не играет.

Answer (score 0):

*В дополнение к ответу выше:*

Несколько строк можно табулировать вместе, если они выделены курсором.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Tab - увеличит отступ (сместит вправо)

Shift+Tab - уменьшит отступ (сместит влево)